# absolute position even within relative is different in different laptops specially in chrome

Tags: css, google-chrome

I've a parent div with position relative and the child div is with absolute. But even it is displaying incorrectly (shifting one button) in different laptops specially I faced this for my website only in chrome. But when prepared this for the question, now it's displaying differently in firefox too. But anyway in firefox it's positioning properly even after doing `Ctrl+Scrolling up or down`

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <button type="button" id="one">one</button>
    <div><img class="img-body" src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/7R6js.jpg" alt="guiness" /></div>
</div>
```

```css
*{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
.wrapper{
    position: relative;
    margin: 0 auto;
    text-align: center;
    display: table;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
}
#one{
    position: absolute;
    top: 369px;
    left:210px;
    background: url(https://i.stack.imgur.com/EvIG1.jpg) no-repeat;
    width:143px;
    height: 60px;
    border:none;
    font-size: 0;
}
.img-body{
    max-width: 100%;
}
```

[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/fqZn3/2/embedded/result/)

How should I manage the position so that it wouldn't look different?

Comment: that's because your wrapper has the size of the image, but what exactly do you want to achieve with the image? I guess you want to mark the button as active, right?

Comment: yes, you are right. And thank you for informing that because of image.

Comment: in that case you should just position the buttons normaly(depends on what you want to achieve^^) and change their styling with css

Comment: That's what i was saying. Positioning works differently.

Comment: Well, with the approach you are doing you won't get it to work(positioning doesnt work differently it's because of different resolutions), you should use normal(static) positioning for the buttons or is there some special reason why you want to do it that way? And why do you have the "background-image" as normal 'img' in a 'div', if thats for resizing than I didnt ask^^, but more importantl why are the buttons drawn on the background?

Comment: Thanks mate. I already solved my problem as you were saying it's because of size for different resolution. And going to delete my quesiton.